# Symfony2 pass variable from controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, controller

I have this controller.php

```php
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TechappStatsBundle:ParentForm');
    $data = $repository->findBy(array(),array('id' => 'desc'),1,0); 

    $formulaire = new ParentForm();

    $parent= $this->get('form.factory')->create(new ParentFormType(),$formulaire);

    if ($parent->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($formulaire);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('TechappStatsBundle:Stats:index.html.twig',array("res" => $data,
        "parentform"=>$parent->createView(),));
```

I want to check the variable `res` in my view with js if it is equals to a specific value or not but I don't know how to pass it.

Comment: does your JS reside in the `index.html.twig` template? or in a separate JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the parameters from controller like:

```
return $this->render('TechappStatsBundle:Stats:index.html.twig', array(
                "res" => "Your data here"));
```

And you can access the "res" parameter in index.html.twig like:

```
{% block js %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
var res = '{{ res }}';
alert(res);
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

My option always is send it in a **data-value**,

You can do something like

```
<div id="res-result" data-res="{{ res }}" style="display: none;">
```

The div doesn't need to be hidden, if it's something related with a div I always put it inside the div related, even if it's not hidden

And then from Jquery:

```
resValue = $('#res-result').data('res');
```

Having the JS file outside of the HTML is the cleanest way IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to Javascript, you can update your view to either:

- Add an hidden input (if this is a form) that contains the value of the data
- Add data to a DIV or P (or whatever) that you hide with CSS
- Add an attribute to a specific field, for example `data-<field>`

Once you get it, you can easily fetch the value from `jQuery`.